How to get folder contents in flutter android app?
I'm trying to build an app to sync a folder on my mobile with Google Drive. My sync logic involves hashing all the files and storing them. However, when I run the following function, it returns a fileCount of 0.
Things I’ve Done:

The app has read, write, and manage permissions for Android.
The folder input is correct, and it contains files like images and PDFs.

import 'dart:io';


Future<int> getFolderHash(Directory folder) async {
try {
if (await folder.exists()) {
Get the list of all files and directories recursively
List<FileSystemEntity> entities = folder.listSync(recursive: true);
print(await folder.list().toList());

int fileCount = entities.whereType<File>().length;
print(entities);
return fileCount;
else {
      return 0;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    return 0;
  }
}

